# git addでエラーが出る: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database

Tags: linux, git, vagrant, virtualbox

環境
vagrantにてubuntu18.04を動かしており、git init、git addを行った際に`git add .`で下記のエラーが表示された。
VirtualBox：バージョン 6.0.6 r130049

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
error: READ.md: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file READ.md
fatal: adding files failed
```

ネットの記事を読むと権限の問題ということで `ls -l .git/objects`で権限を調べてみました。

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  96 Jun 27 08:46 b6
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 160 Jun 27 08:54 e4
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  96 Jun 27 08:43 ff
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  64 Jun 27 08:42 info
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  64 Jun 27 08:42 pack
```

出力結果：`ls -l .git`

```
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  23 Jun 27 08:42 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  64 Jun 27 08:42 branches
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 111 Jun 27 08:42 config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  73 Jun 27 08:42 description
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 416 Jun 27 08:42 hooks
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  96 Jun 27 08:42 info
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 224 Jun 27 08:49 objects
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 128 Jun 27 08:42 refs
```

ここの方と同じエラーだと思うんですけど、なぜsudoを付けて上手く行くのか分かりません。
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10913

実際`sudo git add .`で上手く行きました。しかし毎回sudo付けるの嫌なので何か解決方法があると助かります。
これを見るとオーナーは読み書き検索可能なので権限に問題はなさそうなのですが、何が原因でしょうか？
ご存知の方がいらしたらご教授頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `ls -ld .git/objects/` (`-d`オプション付き)の結果はどうなるでしょうか。また、(私も検索して出てきた対処を見てみただけですが)`objects`直下のディレクトリの権限だけでなく、それ以降のファイルの権限の問題の可能性もあるように思われます。

Comment: 'drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 224 Jun 27 08:49 .git/objects/'このような結果になりました。上記の権限がobjects以降の権限ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: 参照しているリンク先の内容を読む限り、Vagrant と仮想環境 (VirtualBox) のバージョンによる問題じゃないか、と書かれています。 / 質問本文には Vagrant としか記載されていないので、実際に使用している仮想環境やバージョン等も確認してみてください。

Comment: そうみたいです。ただVirtualBoxのバージョンを変更した時にVagrantとの相性の問題で環境が壊れてしまったので可能であればバージョン変更を行わずに解決したいです。

Answer (score 1):

`.git/` ディレクトリ以下には細かなサブディレクトリがあるので、個別の原因となるファイルを特定するよりは一括で権限を変更してしまう方が手っ取り早いかもしれません。

**所有者とグループを変更**

```
$ chown -R vagrant.vagrant .git
```

**読み取り + 書き込み権限を追加**

```
$ chmod -R ug+rw .git
```

参考:
[can't add file to git repository but can change / commit - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7864872)

Comment: このドットは何を意味しているのですか？vagrantだけではダメなのでしょうか？

Comment: 上記のコードを実行してもまだ同じエラーが出ます。

Comment: ドットは `chown` で所有者とグループをまとめて変更する際の方法ですが、うまくいかないのであれば `chown -R vagrant .git` で実行してみてください。

Comment: Ubuntu の場合、`.` ではなく `:`(colon) を使います。`chown -R vagrant:vagrant .git`

Comment: どちらも上手く行きませんでした。新しくls -l .gitの出力結果も記載しました。

Comment: ```sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant .git```だとどうでしょうか。